# regex perl replace

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file and the word is present in the middle of the line, based on the word need to replace from starting of the line till the pattern matched.

Sample line:

`the browser separates off the name/value pairs and other information which is sent in the header and puts it in`

Here we need to find the word `other` and replace from the starting of the line till the word `other` with `the`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which programming language do you want to do this?

Comment: We need considerably more to be able to answer. See [ask]. At the very least, sample input and output, and what you've tried so far and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are expecting this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {  $_=~s/^((?:(?!other).)*)other//i;  print $_;  }

__DATA__
the browser separates off the name/value pairs and other information which is sent in the header and puts it in
```

Output:

```
 information which is sent in the header and puts it in
```